# Node App Logging "Undefined" after starting server

Tags: node.js, logging, heroku, koa

I've got a simple node/koa back-end that I'm deploying to heroku. When I run the app on herokua, I get the following logs:

```
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: > name-app@1.0.0 start /app
app[web.1]: > node ./server.js
app[web.1]:undefined
app[web.1]:   --> GET /dashboard 200 466ms 4b
```

The single 'undefined' log is a mystery to my. Otherwise it's a perfectly function app.

Does anybody have an idea why this 'undefined' line might be logged? Or how to track down where it is coming from?

Comment: You have to share your config file your log config file and your node start file.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I seemed to have found a solution. I added a single console.log in my server.js file, and now instead of displaying the "undefined" line, it prints out the log I added, as seen below:

```
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: > squarify-app@1.0.0 start /app
app[web.1]: > node ./server.js
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: SERVER UP
```